# Apache Virtual host not working for www domains

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I am trying to redirect to access the site with url:  www.example.com 
but it is giving me 403 forbidden.
site works with example.com , https://www.example.com  https://example.com

here is my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost :*80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/asd/sites/example.com/public_html


  <Directory /home/asd/sites/example.com/public_html>
    AllowOverride all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   Require all granted
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ServerAdmin  example.com@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /home/asd/sites/example.com/public_html


    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /home/asd/ssl_certs/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/asd/ssl_certs/example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/asd/ssl_certs/example.com.intermediate.crt


<Directory /home/asd/sites/example.com/public_html>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    AllowOverride all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have tried enabling and disabling 000-default.conf as well. but if I enable that then the www.example goes to apache root index.html

https://www.example.com works fine though.

I have been trying to make it work for hours but I am unable to do so.Any help will be apprreciated.

I want all traffic go from non http to https and www to non www.

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you've got both `example.com` and `www.example.com` in your hosts file. What do the logs say for the problematic requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that it was a typo. Spent my whole day figuring out the issue.

It was:

```
 <VirtualHost :*80>
```

which should be:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: I did not notice this change for long. Happened to me exact same thing. I did not notice this issue at all for long :)